# Java Scanner skip a row of dashes

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I have a file that has two columns, one for full names (first name and last name) and one for ID numbers. The file also has a header with "Name" and "ID", and right below the header and above all the entries, there is a a line of dashes separated by spaces. It looks like this:

```
NAME        ID
------      ------
John Snow   0001
Tyrion      0002
```

I want to be able to skip this row of dashes and I've been trying to use `Scanner.skip()` with no avail. I already set up within a while loop a regex to split the spaces between columns and an if statement to bypass the column headers.

Answer (score 1):

You could proably use a `BufferedReader`instead of a Scanner. It has a readLine() method that could be used then to skip those dashes.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(... your input here...);
String s;
while((s=reader.readLine())!=null) {
   if (s.startWith("--")
       continue;
   // do some stuffs

}
```

EDIT:
If you want to be sure that the lines contains only dashes and spaces you could use:

```
s.matches("[\\- ]+")
```

which will match only if your line contains dashes and blanks

Comment: Same solution for me. I will instead check if the row contains only useless chars so I'll be sure not to loose some data as "--Doe" for example.. but BufferedReader is better for me too :)

Comment: @guillaume-polet, What is the reason for BufferedReader seems better than Scanner ?

Comment: I wonder the same. I'm going to try it later because I'm not getting anywhere with skip() or useDelimiter(). It keeps reading the dash lines.

Comment: I should mention that I'm doing this in Android, loading the file data into a File object and reading with a Scanner object.

Comment: @Roberto Well, a BufferedReader is more adequate to read text and mainly it uses an internal buffer to access the underlying stream. In the case of reading a file, the performance gain is really significant so you should really favor BufferedReader instead of Scanner

Comment: I got it! `scan.skip("[-\\s]*");`

Answer (score 0):

If the first two lines are always static, try this-

```
reader.readLine(); //reads first line, Name ID and does nothing
reader.readLine(); //reads second line, ---- ---- and does nothing
//start scanning the data from now.
while(!EOF){
String line = reader.readLine();
//process the data.
}
```

In this way you can eliminate overhead of comparing each and every line with "--".

Comment: That's what I'm doing at the moment. It works but I feel kind of 'dirty' about it, haha.

Answer (score 0):

```
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(//File with Exension);

Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(fileReader);

fileScan.useDelimiter("\\-")

while(fileScan.hasNext()){

   //Store the contents without '-'
   fileScan.next();
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm not getting anywhere with skip() or useDelimiter(). It keeps reading the dash lines. I've used "\\-" and "[\\- ]+" to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using Scanner, then try this :

```
String curLine;

while (scan.hasNext()){
    curLine = scan.readLine();
    if(!curLine.startsWith("----") {
        .... //whatever code you have for lines that don't contain the dashes

    }
}
```